# Problems with utils.validate_py_environment in Custom Environment

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I would like to ask you help understanding what reason I cannot run utils.validate_py_environment successfully in my custom environment. If I run a sequence of actions manually, instead, the environment works without problems.

Here is my environment (it's a microgrid containing a home consumption, a PV generator and a Battery Bank):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import abc
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tf_agents.environments import py_environment
from tf_agents.environments import tf_environment
from tf_agents.environments import tf_py_environment
from tf_agents.environments import utils
from tf_agents.specs import array_spec
from tf_agents.environments import wrappers
from tf_agents.environments import suite_gym
from tf_agents.trajectories import time_step as ts

tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()

class MicroGridEnv(py_environment.PyEnvironment):
    """
    This class simulates the net amount of energy of the microgrid viewed from
    the battery. That is the difference between generation and consumption of
    energy

    1. Actions: We have 2 actions. Action 0: charge the battery, and action 1: discharge the battery
    2. Observations: [Net Load, Energy available in battery, prognostic of Net Load (next 24 h),
    n° of cycles]
    3. Reward: - 1 per each cycle reached, - 2 if there's a lack of supply for the customer
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._action_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(),
            dtype=np.int32,
            minimum=0, maximum= 1,
            name='action'
        )
        self._observation_spec =  array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
            shape=(4,),
            dtype=np.float32,
            minimum=[-1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0],
            maximum=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1e35],
            name='observation'
        )
        self._state = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self._episode_ended = False

    def action_spec(self):
        return self._action_spec

    def observation_spec(self):
        return self._observation_spec

    def _reset(self):
        self._state = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self._episode_ended = False
        return ts.restart(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.float32))

    def _step(self, action):

        if self._episode_ended:
            # The last action ended the episode. Ignore the current action and start
            # a new episode.
            return self.reset()

        # First, we see if the episode has ended
        if self._state[0] < 0:
            self._episode_ended = True
    
        # Make sure battery actions are witten here
        if action == 1:
            self._state += np.array([0.1, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)
        elif action == 0:
            self._state += np.array([-0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0], dtype=np.float32)
        else:
            raise ValueError('action should be 0 or 1')

        print(self._state)

        # After battery acts, we have to update system dynamics:
        # - Shutdown condition (episode ends if there's a lack of supply)
        if self._state[0] < 0:
            self._episode_ended = True

        if self._episode_ended:
            reward = np.array([self._state[0] - self._state[3]], dtype=np.float32)
            return ts.termination(
                self._state,
                reward
            )
        else:
            return ts.transition(
                self._state,
                reward=0
            )
```

Here is the main code, that executes both ways to test the environment:

```
environment = MicroGridEnv()
print(f"environment MicrogridEnv created")
print(f"action_spec: {environment.action_spec()}")
print(f"time_step_spec.observation: {environment.time_step_spec().observation}")
print(f"time_step_spec.step_type: {environment.time_step_spec().step_type}")
print(f"time_step_spec.discount: {environment.time_step_spec().discount}")
print(f"time_step_spec.reward: {environment.time_step_spec().reward}")

print('Simulating 5 actions')

action = np.array(1, dtype=np.int32)
time_step = environment.reset()
print(time_step)
time_step = environment.step(action)
print(time_step)
time_step = environment.step(action)
print(time_step)
action = np.array(0, dtype=np.int32)
time_step = environment.step(action)
print(time_step)
time_step = environment.step(action)
print(time_step)
time_step = environment.step(action)
print(time_step)

utils.validate_py_environment(environment, episodes=5)
```

And here is the output:

```
environment MicrogridEnv created
action_spec: BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='action', minimum=0, maximum=1)
time_step_spec.observation: BoundedArraySpec(shape=(4,), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='observation', minimum=[-1.  0. -1.  0.], maximum=[1.e+00 1.e+00 1.e+00 1.e+35])
time_step_spec.step_type: ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='step_type')
time_step_spec.discount: BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='discount', minimum=0.0, maximum=1.0)
time_step_spec.reward: ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='reward')
Simulating 5 actions
TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(0)})
[ 0.1 -0.1  0.   0. ]
TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([ 0.1, -0.1,  0. ,  0. ]),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(1)})
[ 0.2 -0.2  0.   0. ]
TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([ 0.2, -0.2,  0. ,  0. ]),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(1)})
[ 0.1 -0.1  0.   0. ]
TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([ 0.1, -0.1,  0. ,  0. ]),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(1)})
[0. 0. 0. 0.]
TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(1)})
[-0.1  0.1  0.   0. ]
TimeStep(
{'discount': array([0.], dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([-0.1,  0.1,  0. ,  0. ]),
 'reward': array([-0.1], dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array([2])})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/evilc/PycharmProjects/MG_Research/MG_environment.py", line 126, in <module>
    utils.validate_py_environment(environment, episodes=5)
  File "C:\Users\evilc\anaconda3\envs\research_2021\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\utils.py", line 72, in validate_py_environment
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Given `time_step`: TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(0)}) does not match expected `time_step_spec`: TimeStep(
{'discount': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='discount', minimum=0.0, maximum=1.0),
 'observation': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(4,), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='observation', minimum=[-1.  0. -1.  0.], maximum=[1.e+00 1.e+00 1.e+00 1.e+35]),       
 'reward': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='reward'),
 'step_type': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='step_type')})
```

Tank you in advance for any help can give me.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: Given `time_step`: TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': **array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)**,
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(0)}) does not match expected `time_step_spec`: TimeStep(
{'discount': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='discount', minimum=0.0, maximum=1.0),
 'observation': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(4,), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='observation', minimum=[-1.  0. -1.  0.], maximum=[1.e+00 1.e+00 1.e+00 1.e+35]),       
 'reward': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='reward'),
 'step_type': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='step_type')})
```

take a look at:

> ValueError: Given `time_step`: TimeStep

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

is the expected observation and you are returning the observations without especify the `dtype=float32`

```
TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([ 0.1, -0.1,  0. ,  0. ]),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(1)})
```